# Ghostscript: PDF total pages

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I'm using Ghostscript library API (wrapping from C#) to print PDF documents from my application.
With the '*-dFirstPage*' and '*-dLastPage*' parameters I'm able to select an range of pages to be printed, but how about the total number of a PDF's pages?

It is not very nice to allow a user to select a page interval from 2 to 10 when, let me say, the PDF document has only 4 pages.

Consider that I'm using Ghostscript library through the *gsapi_init_with_args* API library call.

Comment: PDFs MUST declare their number of pages in their metadata catalog. You could als run s.th. like *gs -q -c "(in.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"* to make Ghostscript count the pages.

Comment: @pipitas Hello and thanks for your help; if i understud, i have to use "(in.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit" as input parameter of a GS call? If yes, 'in.pdf' will be the input file but what about '(r)'? Thanks again.

Comment: Just use '(r)' as is. It's a Ghostscript internal macro telling Ghostscript to read/run the '(in.pdf)' file... Yes, the only variable is `in.pdf` -- replace it with [path+]filename of your PDF.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Ghostscript can count and display the number of pages of a PDF on `stdout`. The commandline is

```
gswin32c ^
  -q ^
  -dNODISPLAY ^
  -c "(input.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"
```

Here all the `-c "..."` stuff is a PostScript commandline snippet (using a few GS internal command extensions). And *input.pdf* is the PDF filename (could also be a full path like `(c:/path/to/my.pdf)`).

However, a better and faster tool for **this** kind of job would be to use `pdfinfo` (part of the XPDF-utilities, also available on Windows).

---

***Update:***

@ebyrob wants to know if one can modify my example command line so that it also *displays* the PDF in a single operation. Try this:

```
gswin32c ^
  -q ^
  -c "(input.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount =" ^
  -f input.pdf
```

Well, it's not a single operation -- it's just two different operations in a single commandline.

Comment: Could this be modified to read metadata while also displaying the PDF image in a single operation?  (Say with `-sDEVICE=display` and friends specified)  And also, when reading file from `stdin`?  (ie: gswin32 filename of `-`)  Running just: `-c "pdfpagecount"` seemed to give me an "operation doesn't exist" error.  Including `runpdfbegin` game me invalid file name.

Comment: @ebyrob: you need every single character in my command example (you may only change '*input.pdf*' to a different existing filename or -path. You can't just skip any part as you feel like...

Comment: I was thinking something like: `gswin64c - -c "currentfile runpdfbegin pdfpagecount ==" < input.pdf` would help.  But, runpdfbegin uses `setfileposition` which isn't supported, apparently, by `stdin` or `currentfile`.  Working entirely in memory with the DLL interface makes reading from the filesystem a bit troublesome.  my "invalid filename" came from `(%stdin) runpdfbegin` and variations with `file` command.  Basically I couldn't specify `stdin` to `file` or `runpddfbegin` successfully.

Comment: Looks like `%` was being removed by command line, `%%` works in NT batch script.  So, I'm back to `setfileposition` breaking `runpdfbegin` for anything like stdin or in-memory operation.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle I think I found something that might work here:  http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=691739  Of course, I'm still going to have to skip the `input.pdf` parts...  Did I forget to mention in my first comment that I wanted to read from `stdin`?

Comment: Is there a way to capture the output of this command (meaning the number of pages)? I'm trying to run this from within python using the ghostscript package, but it just runs and completes successfully, I would like to write it to a variable or a file.

Comment: If you are getting /invalidfileaccess error see Ger Hobbelt's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61310729/8542816

Answer (score 4):

For people having issues in ghostscript >9.50 add --permit-file-read=input.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I tried to make this script:

```
gswin32c ^
  -q ^
  -c "(input.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount =" ^
  -f input.pdf
```

work in a **c# wrapped** solution and kept getting error "/undefinedfilename". In this case ensure that your filepath has Slashes "/" as DirectorySeperator and not Backslashes "\". I know Kurt Pfeifle already wrote it, but it happened to me i just overlooked it.

Comment: If you want to use backslashes, you have to use two of them each time...

Answer (score 1):

### In Windows systems:

> "path to gs exec" -q -dNODISPLAY -dNOSAFER --permit-file-read="path to
> your file" -c "(""path to your file"") (r) file runpdfbegin
> pdfpagecount = quit"

### Remarks:

- Just change where is 'path to...' with your path, leave the rest as is.
- On the -c path you must use double slashes or unix like ones. Ex: C:\\youfile.pdf (good), C:/youfile.pdf (good), C:\yourfile.pdf (bad).

### Example:

- path: *C:\Temp\Some Folder\myFile.pdf*
- gs path: *C:\Temp\Some Folder\gs\bin\gswin64c.exe*
- path -c 1: *C:\\Temp\\Some Folder\\myFile.pdf*
- path -c 2: *C:/Temp/Some Folder/myFile.pdf*

**Commands:**

```
"C:\Temp\Some Folder\gs\bin\gswin64c.exe" -q -dNODISPLAY -dNOSAFER --permit-file-read="C:\Temp\Some Folder\myFile.pdf" -c "(""C:\\Temp\\Some Folder\\myFile.pdf"") (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"

"C:\Temp\Some Folder\gs\bin\gswin64c.exe" -q -dNODISPLAY -dNOSAFER --permit-file-read="C:\Temp\Some Folder\myFile.pdf" -c "(""C:/Temp/Some Folder/myFile.pdf"") (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"
```

Answer (score 0):

To sum up some of the above separate comments for windows users to avoid needing to alter between / and \\ , to show the total number of pages can be set as a shortcut for drag and drop or "sendTo", **by first switching to a working directory.**

```
@echo off & cd /d "%~dp1" & "C:\path to gs\bin\gs.exe" -q --permit-file-read="%~nx1" -c "(%~nx1) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit" & pause
```

where gs.exe is one of the windows c(onsole) variants gswin32c.exe or gswin64c.exe

- The cd /c "%~dp1" will switch console to quoted file drive path
- The full quoted path to "GSwin..c.exe" calls it safely and remotely
- -q will suppress (not show) the start message
- since version 9.5+ the --permit-file-read="file name" is advised / required
- -c "(%~nx1) does not need the quotes for name.xtension
- if running a cmd as a shortcut, pause is required to see the result

**beware only use on files** you trust as your overriding GS -dSAFER restrictions.

[image]

**[UPDATE]**
See Lakedaimon answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77741851/10802527
and using that newer method a shortcut leading to this file in GS folder,
Show PDF Num Pages.cmd

```
@echo off
color cF
MODE CON: COLS=40 LINES=12
title "%~n1.pdf" number of pages 
cd /d "%~dp1"
"%~dp0\gswin32c.exe" -q -dBATCH -dPDFINFO "%~n1.pdf" 2>%temp%\output.txt
findstr  "has" %temp%\output.txt
pause
del %temp%\output.txt
```

should allow drag and drop or sendto  (note a PDF may be a portfolio collection of multiple files and I have not included a summary function)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anybody just tearing their hair out over this not working (like I was), **one** of the caret (^) characters is actually required on the command line and **none** of the newlines are.  Use forward slash (/) path delimiters and no double or double-double quotes (" or "") around the file name.

```
gswin32c -q -dNODISPLAY ^ -c "(C:/Temp/Some Input.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"
```

Comment: By the way, none of any of this - my answer or others - work with the GhostScript API.  It always gives 'undefinedfilename' and hangs the API in the bargain.

Answer (score 0):

With GhostScript >= 9.56 there is a new parameter which works well:

```
gswin64 -q -dNODISPLAY -dPDFINFO .\pdf-test.pdf
```

It returns "File has 1 page" or "File has X pages" as well as meta data like Author, Creator etc.

More info on [-dPDFINFO](https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Use.html#page-parameters) especially https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Use.html#dpdfinfo

Comment: yes -dDISPLAY is completely optional as -dBATCH as well. It depends on the usecase. If you run this via command line -dBATCH is useful if you call ghostscript dll via interop out of an app -dNODISPLAY is useful.