# Read amount of pages in PDF using ImageMagick C++ API without reading all images

Tags: c++, pdf, imagemagick

I need to read a PDF's page size rather cheaply, so my user can select specific pages (and load them in higher detail).

The only way I see to do this with Magick++ API is using the [STL](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/STL.html) call `readImages`.  This does load in all the pages of the PDF as `Magick::Images`, and gets quite expensive for large PDF documents (order of 50 pages takes about 15s on my machine.)

I did read [a post](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=13301) on ImageMagick's forums that speaks about the `ReadOptions` class (not documented at time of writing) you can pass to `readImages` method to read lower density image, but this still takes too long. (About 10s). None of the other options on `ReadOptions` really make a big difference with regards to speed.

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
    std::vector<Magick::Image> PDFImageList;
    Magick::ReadOptions readOptions;
    readOptions.density(Magick::Geometry(2,2));
    readOptions.size(Magick::Geometry(1,1));
    readOptions.depth(8);
    // This call takes too long.
    Magick::readImages(&PDFImageList, m_pathToPDFFile, readOptions);
    int numberOfPages = PDFImageList.size();
```

I have also tried the `Magick::Image.ping()` method, and can't find any data that it returns that relates to the page number.

Any other attribute or undocumented ImageMagick++ feature that I can try to get the page count cheaply?

Comment: Not sure if this is any help or any faster, hence just a comment. Try this at the command-line and see if it helps and if you can adapt it to C++... `identify -format "%s\n"  file.pdf`

Comment: There's a `Magick::Image.png` option, but that'll take about the same amount of time for PDFs. I half remember ImageMagick delegating PDF format to [another library](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/). It might be faster to use that API directly.

Comment: @MarkSetchell the command line does seem to work, but seems just as slow. Also I don't want to add the ImageMagick installation as a dependence on the user's PC.
 
@emcconville, I did try the `ping` method, but nothing on that call had info about the total pages in the PDF file.  I'll try looking at the GhostScript dependency and see how far that gets me.

Comment: Maybe CPDF... http://community.coherentpdf.com... `cpdf -pages yourFile.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

Using another question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4829240/8524) and Qt's process class, the program now runs the following on the commandline:

```
gs -q -dNODISPLAY -c "(input.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"
```

Which returns page number as last line of standard out.  Since the gs executable is a requirement of ImageMagick's PDF reading functionality, I'm happy with this solution.  It is also quite fast. (Less than a second for the ~50 page PDF)