# Count no. of pages in a PDF file while uploading in Javascript

Tags: pdf

I want to **calculate number of pages in a PDF file** while uploading to my application by Javascript in Client Side. I want some help for this. I Google this topic but I couldn't get any appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you are uploading PDF file to the server anyway then it is better to do this on the server-side, there are lot of options depending what is your target platform).

For example, you may use the open source [Ghostscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4826485/ghostscript-pdf-total-pages) to count total number of pages.