# gGt an output file with a count of PDF pages for each file with Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

This code works for me, except all my files are on a network drive. In the example below, the code works only if the file is in the root directory (`c:\`) as an example.

Do I have to replace `input.pdf` with something like `d:\hello space folder\filefolder\input.pdf`? I tried this, but got a sleuth of errors saying directory not found. I tried to do netuse and map the network main drive folder, but that didn't work either.

```
gswin32c ^
  -q ^
  -dNODISPLAY ^
  -c "(input.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a single backslash in a PostScript string, because that's the escape character. For the path delimiter you either need to use two backslashes `\\` to escape the escape, or use a forward slash `/` instead.

Comment: I apologize, I am new to ghostscript. Would you be kind to show in the code above what you meant?

Comment: (d:/hello space folder/filefolder/input.pdf)

Comment: much appreciated! this did work! here is the final script as informational for folks. NET USE u: /DELETE
NET USE u: "YOUR PATH"   /PERSISTENT:YES

NET USE b: /DELETE
NET USE b: "PATH FOR LOG FILE"           /PERSISTENT:YES
CHCP 1252 > NULL

"c:\program files (x86)\gs\gs8.70\bin\gswin32c" -q  -dNoDisplay -c "('u:/some folder/filename.pdf') (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit" > b:\filenamepages.txt

Answer (score 2):

Note that since GhostScript 9.50 the SAFER mode has been turned ON by default, resulting in `/invalidfileaccess` errors like these, which would not go away by making sure all directory separators in thee path are `/` forward slashes, fiddling with the current path, etc.

This has cost me quite some hair and several hours today, but anno 2020 you'll need to do something like this:

## Solution 1: Add source path to the accepted list using `--permit-file-read=<path>` to make the `/invalidfileaccess` go away

```
gs -q --permit-file-read=d:/ -dNODISPLAY -c "(d:/test.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"
```

i.e. make sure that the path to the PDF you're loading *in the PostScript command/script* is in the approved list a.k.a. permission list, [using one of the `--permit-file-xyz` commandline arguments](https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.50/Use.htm#Safer).

## Solution 2: Quick hack with `-I<path>` to make the `/invalidfileaccess` go away

```
gs -q -Id:/ -dNODISPLAY -c "(d:/test.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"
```

i.e. make sure that the path to the PDF you're loading *in the PostScript command/script* is in the approved list a.k.a. permission list.

The `-Id:/` in the example above is just a quick hack to make sure the source path of your path is on that list, given this bit [from the official documentation](https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.50/Use.htm#NoSafer):

> Finally, paths supplied on the command line (such as those in -I, -sFONTPATH parameters) are added to the permitted reading list. Similarly, paths read during initialisation from Fontmap, cidfmap, and the platform specific font file enumeration (e.g. fontconfig on Unix systems) are automatically added to the permit read lists.

### Note / Aside about expectations when using `-I` like that:

Another surprise for me was that

```sh
gs -q  -I d:/ -dNODISPLAY -c "(test.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"
```

i.e. specifying the source path of the PDF in the `-I` include set and then *omitting* it in the PostScript command, **still** gave me an `/invalidfileaccess` so make sure to specify a proper **absolute path** for the PDF you're loading.

## Notes

### Applies to PostScript scripts, not the `-f` commandline

This problem only occurs with file loads inside `-c` PostScript commands, *not* with PDF/PS source files specified directly on the commandline using `-f <file>`.

### How to check if this is your actual problem

#### Test 1: Try the same without the extra `-I<path>` or `--permit-file-read=<path>`: does the error return? If yes, then bingo!

When this commandline (note the missing `-Id:/` or `--permit-file-read=d:/` is the only change):

```
gs -q -dNODISPLAY -c "(d:/test.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"
```

gives you the "invalid file access" error as in:

```
   Error: /invalidfileaccess in --file--
   Operand stack:
      (d:/test.pdf)   (r)
   Execution stack:
      %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
   Dictionary stack:
      --dict:737/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:75/200(L)--
   Current allocation mode is local
   Last OS error: Permission denied
   GPL Ghostscript 9.52: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

than you quite probably have [a `-dSAFER` problem](https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.50/News.htm#28_Incompatible_changes) which is fixed by the above addition of the **PDF source directory** to the accepted paths list (see also [the GhostScript documentation at 'NOSAFER'](https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/Use.htm#NoSafer) and onwards including the section about `--permit-file-read=pathlist` et al.

#### Test 2: Does the problem go away when you run with `-dNOSAFER`? If yes, then bingo!

When this commandline:

```
gs -q -dNOSAFER -dNODISPLAY -c "(d:/test.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount = quit"
```

works okay, then that's a sure sign you need either of the solutions described above to get rid of the `/invalidfileaccess` error.

#### WARNING: Older answers you find on the Net probably won't work anymore

As I've looked at quite a few discussions, both here at SO and elsewhere, including various bugtrackers, nobody seems to mention this anywhere as all those pages/entries are from before GhostScript release 9.50 and 2019AD.

Quoting [from the 9.50 change notes](https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.50/News.htm):

> The file access control capability (enable with `-dSAFER`) has been completely rewritten, with a ground-up rethink of the design. For more details, see: SAFER.
>
> It is important to note that `-dSAFER` now only enables the file access controls, and no longer applies restrictions to standard Postscript functionality (specifically, restrictions on `setpagedevice`). If your application relies on these Postscript restrictions, see `OLDSAFER`, and please get in touch, as we do plan to remove those Postscript restrictions unless we have reason not to.
>
> **IMPORTANT**: File access controls are now enabled by default. In order to run Ghostscript without these controls, see `NOSAFER`
>
> **Important Note for Windows Users**: See below under [Incompatible Changes](https://ghostscript.com/doc/9.50/News.htm#28_Incompatible_changes)

The `SAFER` change is from 2019-09-30 (release 9.50)

Comment: Probably the `-dNOSAFER` is the best way to go